# Macro VBA for creating a Chart in LibreCalc, how to position titles, legends, and chart main into chart area

Tags: vba, position, libreoffice-calc, legend-properties

Macro VBA for creating a Chart in LibreCalc, how to position titles, legends, and chart main into chart area.

I have created a Macro by reading many sources as well developers guides [here Xshapes](https://www.openoffice.org/api/docs/common/ref/com/sun/star/drawing/GenericDrawPage.html) and [ChartLegends - Automatic position](https://www.openoffice.org/api/docs/common/ref/com/sun/star/chart/ChartLegend.html)

It says that "boolean - AutomaticPosition   - If this property is true the position is calculated by the application automatically. Setting this property to false will have no effect. Instead use the interface ::com::sun::star::drawing::XShape to set a concrete position.  "

So I was searching for Xshape but nothing found about legend and title positioning inside a Chart / graph.

What I am doing wrongly? What I must do in order to

- a) Change the position of chart titles inside the Chart
- b) Change the
  position of chart Legend inside the Chart (not referring to Alignment
  1,2,3,4)
- c) Change the position of chart itself inside the Chart Area
  (as well its size)

Note that I have installed Xray tool, but no help.

```
Sub CreateCalcWithSimpleChart

Dim oSheet    'Sheet containing the chart
Dim oRect     'How big is the chart
Dim oCharts   'Charts in the sheet
Dim oChart    'Created chart
Dim oAddress  'Address of data to plot
Dim sName$    'Chart name
Dim oChartDoc 'Embedded chart object
Dim oTitle    'Chart title object 
Dim oDiagram  'Inserted diagram (data).
Dim sDataRng$ 'Where is the data
Dim oCalcDoc


oCalcDoc = CreateCalcForChart()
sName = "Example_01"
sDataRng = "$E$8:$G$19"
oSheets = ThisComponent.getSheets()
oSheet  = oSheets.getbyName("Normality")
oAddress = oSheet.getCellRangeByName( sDataRng ).getRangeAddress()
oCharts = oSheet.getCharts()

If NOT oCharts.hasByName(sName) Then
oRect = createObject("com.sun.star.awt.Rectangle")
oRect.X = 1
oRect.Y = 1
oRect.width = 20000
oRect.Height= 10000
oCharts.addNewByName(sName, oRect, Array(oAddress), True, True)
End If

oChart = oCharts.getByName( sName )  
oChart.setRanges(Array(oAddress))
oChartDoc = oChart.getEmbeddedObject()

' Create a diagram.
oDiagram = oChartDoc.createInstance( "com.sun.star.chart.ChartDiagram" )
oChartDoc.setDiagram( oDiagram )  
oDiagram = oChartDoc.getDiagram()

' Min / Max scale values on x-y axis
  oAxis = oDiagram.getXAxis()
  oAxis.AutoMin = False
  oAxis.AutoMax = False
  oAxis.Min                   = 1
  oAxis.Max                   = 5
  oAxis.CharColor             = RGB(111,0,200)
  oAxis.CharFontName          = "Liberation San"
  oAxis.CharHeight            = 8
  oAxis.AxisTitle.string      ="ccccc"
  oAxis.AxisTitle.CharColor   = RGB(11,0,200)
  oAxis.AxisTitle.CharHeight  = 12
  oAxis.CharPosture           = 0   'Italics
  
  oAxis = oDiagram.getYAxis()
  oAxis.AutoMin = False
  oAxis.AutoMax = False
  oAxis.Min                   = 1
  oAxis.Max                   = 5
  oAxis.CharColor             = RGB(111,0,200)
  oAxis.CharFontName          = "Liberation San"
  oAxis.CharHeight            = 8
  oAxis.AxisTitle.string      ="ccccc"
  oAxis.AxisTitle.CharColor   = RGB(111,0,2)
  oAxis.AxisTitle.CharHeight  = 12
  oAxis.CharPosture           = 0   'Italics
  
  oTitle                      = oChartDoc.getTitle()  
  oTitle.String               = "My title"
  oTitle.CharColor            = RGB(0,0,200)
  oTitle.CharFontName         = "Liberation San"
  oTitle.CharHeight           = 18
  oTitle.CharPosture          = 1   'Italics

  oSubTitle                   = oChartDoc.getSubtitle()  
  oSubTitle.String            = "My title"
  oSubTitle.CharColor         = RGB(0,0,200)
  oSubTitle.CharFontName      = "Liberation San"
  oSubTitle.CharHeight        = 16
  oSubTitle.CharPosture       = 0   'Italics
      
  oDiagram.Wall.FillColor     = RGB(255,255,255) 

  oChartDoc.HasLegend         = True 
  oLegend                     = oChartDoc.getLegend()
  oLegend.AutomaticPosition   = False
  oLegend.Alignment           = 3
  oLegend.CharHeight          = 10
  oLegend.CharFontName        = "Liberation San"
  oLegend.FillColor           = RGB(225,255,255)
  oLegend.CharColor           = RGB(0,0,200)
  oLegend.CharPosture         = 0   'Italics
  
  oLegend.Position =  oLegend.getPosition()
  oLegend.Position.X = 125
  oLegend.Position.Y  =1268
  oLegend.Size =  oLegend.getSize()
  oLegend.Size.Width = 1100
  oLegend.Size.Height = 1100
      
 ' oArea = oDiagram.getDiagram()
 '  Xray oChartDoc.getLegend() 
' Print oDiagram.getDataRowProperties.Value()
 
ColumnColor0 = oDiagram.getDataRowProperties(0)
ColumnColor1 = oDiagram.getDataRowProperties(1)


aCOLOR = RGB(131, 221, 300)
bCOLOR = RGB(1, 1, 1)


    with ColumnColor0
        .FillBackground = False
        .FillStyle = 1
        .FillColor = aCOLOR
    end with

    with ColumnColor1
        .FillBackground = False
        .FillStyle = 1
        .FillColor = aCOLOR
    end with

end sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I searched how to set position and set size of objects in VBA.

You must declare the position and size for each object independently instead of eg. oTitle.Size.X = 100 ; oTitle.Size.Y = 200 which "common" logic may think.

```
' XrayTool that helps to investigate VBA objects. 
' Found here: https://berma.pagesperso-orange.fr/index2.html 
' Download word document and click the button inside to install 
' it.

Sub LoadingLibraries
 BasicLibraries.LoadLibrary("XrayTool")
End Sub


Sub CreateCalcWithSimpleChart

' Definitions of variables
Dim oSheet    'Sheet containing the chart
Dim oRect     'How big is the chart
Dim oCharts   'Charts in the sheet
Dim oChart    'Created chart
Dim oAddress  'Address of data to plot
Dim sName$    'Chart name
Dim oChartDoc 'Embedded chart object
Dim oTitle    'Chart title object 
Dim oDiagram  'Inserted diagram (data).
Dim sDataRng$ 'Where is the data
Dim oCalcDoc  

' it is needed to define Point and Size in order to
' change Position and Size of Chart Objects
Dim Pos_Chart       As New com.sun.star.awt.Point
Dim Pos_Title       As New com.sun.star.awt.Point
Dim Pos_SubTitle    As New com.sun.star.awt.Point
Dim Pos_xTitle      As New com.sun.star.awt.Point
Dim Pos_yTitle      As New com.sun.star.awt.Point
Dim Pos_Legend      As New com.sun.star.awt.Point

Dim Size_Chart      As New com.sun.star.awt.Size
Dim Size_Title      As New com.sun.star.awt.Size
Dim Size_SubTitle   As New com.sun.star.awt.Size
Dim Size_xTitle     As New com.sun.star.awt.Size
Dim Size_yTitle     As New com.sun.star.awt.Size
Dim Size_Legend     As New com.sun.star.awt.Size


' Creation of objects into variables
oCalcDoc    = CreateCalcForChart()
sName       = "Example_01"
sDataRng    = "$E$8:$G$19"
oSheets     = ThisComponent.getSheets()
oSheet      = oSheets.getbyName("Normality")
oAddress    = oSheet.getCellRangeByName( sDataRng ).getRangeAddress()
oCharts     = oSheet.getCharts()


' The size of the whole chart 
If NOT oCharts.hasByName(sName) Then
oRect       = createObject("com.sun.star.awt.Rectangle")
oRect.X     = 1
oRect.Y     = 1
oRect.width = 200
oRect.Height= 1000
oCharts.addNewByName(sName, oRect, Array(oAddress), True, True)
End If


' Getting the Chart for manipulations
oChart     = oCharts.getByName( sName )  
oChart.setRanges(Array(oAddress))
oChartDoc  = oChart.getEmbeddedObject()
oDiagram   = oChartDoc.createInstance( "com.sun.star.chart.ChartDiagram" )
oChartDoc.setDiagram( oDiagram )  
oDiagram   = oChartDoc.getDiagram()


 ' Inside the Chart, Setting Position and Size of the Diagram
  oChartDoc.RefreshAddInAllowed = True
  Pos_Chart.X                   = 1000
  Pos_Chart.Y                   = 800
  Size_Chart.width              = 18000
  Size_Chart.height             = 8000
  oDiagram.setPosition( Pos_Chart )
  oDiagram.setSize(     Size_Chart )

  oDiagram.Wall.FillColor       = RGB(255,255,255) 

  
 ' Min / Max scale values on x-y axis plus Font format
  oXaxis                        = oDiagram.getXAxis()
  oXaxis.AutoMin                = False
  oXaxis.AutoMax                = False
  oXaxis.Min                    = 1
  oXaxis.Max                    = 5
  oXaxis.CharColor              = RGB(111,0,200)
  oXaxis.CharFontName           = "Liberation San"
  oXaxis.CharHeight             = 8
  oXaxis.CharPosture            = 0   'Italics
  
  oYaxis                        = oDiagram.getYAxis()
  oYaxis.AutoMin                = False
  oYaxis.AutoMax                = False
  oYaxis.Min                    = 1
  oYaxis.Max                    = 5
  oYaxis.CharColor              = RGB(111,0,200)
  oYaxis.CharFontName           = "Liberation San"
  oYaxis.CharHeight             = 8
  oYaxis.CharPosture            = 0   'Italics
  
  
  'Position and Size of x axis Title plus Font format
  oXaxis.AxisTitle.string       ="ccccc"
  oXaxis.AxisTitle.CharColor    = RGB(111,0,2)
  oXaxis.AxisTitle.CharFontName = "Liberation San"
  oXaxis.AxisTitle.CharHeight   = 12
  oXaxis.CharPosture            = 0   'Italics
  
  Pos_xTitle.X                  = 1000
  Pos_xTitle.Y                  = 800
  Size_xTitle.width             = 18000
  Size_xTitle.height            = 8000
  oXaxis.setPosition( Pos_xTitle  )
  oXaxis.setSize(     Size_xTitle )

 
  'Position and Size of y axis Title plus Font Format
  oYaxis.AxisTitle.string       ="ccccc"
  oYaxis.AxisTitle.CharColor    = RGB(111,0,2)
  oYaxis.AxisTitle.CharFontName = "Liberation San"
  oYaxis.AxisTitle.CharHeight   = 12
  oYaxis.CharPosture            = 0   'Italics
  
  Pos_yTitle.X                  = 1000
  Pos_yTitle.Y                  = 800
  Size_yTitle.width             = 18000
  Size_yTitle.height            = 8000
  oYaxis.setPosition( Pos_yTitle  )
  oYaxis.setSize(     Size_yTitle )


  ' Formating Chart Title and Chart Subtitle
  oTitle                       = oChartDoc.getTitle()  
  oTitle.String                = "My title"
  oTitle.CharColor             = RGB(0,0,200)
  oTitle.CharFontName          = "Liberation San"
  oTitle.CharHeight            = 18
  oTitle.CharPosture           = 1   'Italics
  
  oSubTitle                    = oChartDoc.getSubtitle()  
  oSubTitle.String             = "My title"
  oSubTitle.CharColor          = RGB(0,0,200)
  oSubTitle.CharFontName       = "Liberation San"
  oSubTitle.CharHeight         = 16
  oSubTitle.CharPosture        = 0   'Italics
  
  
  'Position and Size of Chart Title and Chart Subtitle
  Pos_Title.X                  = 5000
  Pos_Title.Y                  = 0
  Size_Title.width             = 0
  Size_Title.height            = 0
  oTitle.setPosition( Pos_Title  )
  oTitle.setSize(     Size_Title )
    
  Pos_SubTitle.X               = 5000
  Pos_SubTitle.Y               = 800
  Size_SubTitle.width          = 0
  Size_SubTitle.height         = 0
  oSubTitle.setPosition( Pos_SubTitle  )
  oSubTitle.setSize(     Size_SubTitle )
  

  ' Formating Chart Legend  
  oChartDoc.HasLegend           = True 
  oLegend                       = oChartDoc.getLegend()
  oLegend.AutomaticPosition     = False
  oLegend.Alignment             = 3
  oLegend.CharHeight            = 10
  oLegend.CharFontName          = "Liberation San"
  oLegend.FillColor             = RGB(225,255,255)
  oLegend.CharColor             = RGB(0,0,200)
  oLegend.CharPosture           = 0   'Italics

  ' Position and Size of Chart Legend  
  Pos_Legend.X                  = 11000
  Pos_Legend.Y                  = 300
  Size_Legend.width             = 7800
  Size_Legend.height            = 1100
  oLegend.setPosition( Pos_Legend )
  oLegend.setSize(     Size_Legend )


' xray oDiagram      
' Print oDiagram.getDataRowProperties.Value()
 
  ' Setting the Colour of bars pper case 
  ColumnColor0 = oDiagram.getDataRowProperties(0)
  ColumnColor1 = oDiagram.getDataRowProperties(1)

  aCOLOR = RGB(131, 221, 300)
  bCOLOR = RGB(1, 1, 1)

    with ColumnColor0
        .FillBackground = False
        .FillStyle = 1
        .FillColor = aCOLOR
    end with

    with ColumnColor1
        .FillBackground = False
        .FillStyle = 1
        .FillColor = bCOLOR
    end with


end sub
```